# Contact Form email address set in the plugin's setting being changed by Linode server?

Tags: plugin-contactform

I've used the contact form plugin many times with no issues. However I have a site set up on a Linode server and for some reason the from address that I have added in the contact form settings e.g. contactus@mydomain.com is being changed to contactus@localhost.localdomain when the email comes through.

Anyone any ideas what is causing this. I'm thinking it's a server setting but wanted to check the plugin wasn't causing anything weird to happen as well.

Cheers

Comment: I assume you're referring to the "To Email" in the Contact Form settings and not the "From Email", which is the one the end users inputs in the form?  If you look in the `craft_plugins` table in the database for that site, then find the row with the `ContactForm` class name, then find the `settings` column, what is "toEmail" set to there?

Comment: @bradbell it is set to the correct email with the domain name.

Comment: Do you have any other plugins installed that might be listening to Contact Form's [events](https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form/tree/v1#the-contactformbeforesend-event) and interfering?

Comment: @bradbell no just 2 simple ones sendfile and lj_cookies neither are listening.

Comment: @bradbell on further investigation it only seems to want to send to my personal address. Could this be a serverside issue?

Comment: I'm guessing you've got the https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#testToEmailAddress config setting set to your email address.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I've been dissatisfied with the craft cms contact form plugin. Fortunately, this doesn't *need* to be handled with the CMS. I've been using third party tools such as [Formbucket](https://www.formbucket.com) to handle form submissions for several reasons.

1. Reliability is extremely important. Most clients will not tolerate any mistakes regarding lead generation in contact forms.
2. Feature rich. Craft's contact form plugin is very barebones and ugly. With formbucket and other form submission collection tools, you can add as many fields as you want instead of segmenting `message`. There is also honeypot and recaptcha fields to keep out spam.

I know this is probably not the answer you were looking for, and I wish you the best with getting it to work, just wanted to let you know how i've been doing it.

PS: I don't work for Formbucket.